# How to integrate $1/(u^2 + u^4)$ du?

Tags: calculus, integration

I did a trig substitution with $x = \tan \theta$ followed by a regular $u$ substitution and I got the integral down to $$\int \frac1{u^2 + u^4}\mathrm du$$I just need a reminder of what this would be in terms of $u$. I figured I could just put $\ln(u^2 + u^4)$ but I'm not sure if there's a nicer way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Use Partial Fractions.

Comment: How do you know that the integral is simple ? Where's the original ? What's $x$ ? What's $\theta$ ??

Comment: It would be interesting to know the original problem, for my feeling is that some of the calculation was not necessary.

Comment: Agreed with Andre. BabaSvoloch, can you post the original question?

Comment: How do you get the cats to stay in the water long enough to complete the ritual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$\frac1{u^2+u^4}=\frac1{u^2}-\frac1{1+u^2}$$
You should be able to compute the first antiderivative and recognize the second.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$ \frac{1}{x^2+x^4} = \frac{1+x^2}{x^2+x^4}-\frac{x^2}{x^2+x^4}=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps do
$$\frac{1}{u^2(1+u^2)}$$
and then do partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

also again subtituting $u=\tan\theta$ gives $du=\sec^2\theta d\theta$

hence $\int\frac{1}{u^2+u^4}du=\int\frac{sec^2\theta}{tan^2\theta(1+tan^2\theta)}d\theta=\int\cot^2\theta d\theta=\int(\csc^2\theta-1)d\theta$

hope you can do it from here